# Retrieving a string from another thread giving periodic crashes

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

In my app I have a thread that is reading data from a file. This thread is also simultaneously updating a "status" String with text like "Reading object 1 of 204", "Loading background image", etc.

In the main application thread, a text Label is displayed, and each frame it retrieves this status String from the loading thread and displays it to the user so they know what the progress is.

I **think** the issue is the threading, somehow, because (rarely) a crash occurs in the text Label while it is setting its text prior to rendering. I feel like it's getting two different values of text and an array index is going out of bounds - point is, it's crashing.

**Loading thread:**

```
// ...loading some stuff
setSavingOpeningStatusText("loading stuff 1");
// ...loading different stuff
setSavingOpeningStatusText("loading stuff 2");
// ...etc
setSavingOpeningStatusText("loading stuff 3);
```

**Main application thread**, upon every update() prior to rendering:

```
statusLabel.setText(loadingThread.getSavingOpeningStatusText());
```

And here are those two get/set functions, in the loading thread:

```
public synchronized String getSavingOpeningStatusText()
{
    return savingLoadingStatusString;
}

private synchronized void setSavingOpeningStatusText(String text)
{
    savingLoadingStatusString = text;
}
```

I thought the synchronized function as the only way of setting/getting this String's value would solve the problem, but it didn't.

Am I doing something wrong above, or am I looking in the wrong spot to figure out this crash?

---

**Edit, the actual crash:**

So again, this is called on the Label every frame:

```
statusLabel.setText(loadingThread.getSavingOpeningStatusText());
```

And afterwards, when drawing occurs:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException
Array is empty.
com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Array.pop (Array.java:323)
com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Pool.obtain (Pool.java:51)
com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.GlyphLayout.setText (GlyphLayout.java:143)
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Label.layout (Label.java:214)
...(bunch of stuff)
*.*.*.App.render (App.java:595)
```

When the frame is drawn, `layout()` is called on the Label where it calculates size and whatnot because of the new text it has been assigned. This is the only Label that crashes like this out of countless ones throughout the app. And again, is very rare, which is what makes me think its threading related even though its some Pool that crashes (I think it's trying to fetch a certain number of glyphs from a pool, but that number changes halfway through because the String is changing across threads?).

Comment: please show the declaration of `savingLoadingStatusString`

Comment: What do you mean by "a crash occurs"? What happens exactly?

Comment: @Bohemian is simply `private String savingLoadingStatusString;` declared in the class which contains the function that the loading thread runs

Comment: @rustyx appended it to the post

Comment: Try making it threadsafe by changing it to: `private volatile String savingLoadingStatusString;`